# Language of all words of the form $ww$ is in $\mathsf{NTIME}(n)$

Tags: turing-machines, time-complexity, definitions

> Show that the language $\{ ww \mid w \in \{0,1\}^* \}$ is in $\mathsf{NTIME}(n)$.

I have a doubt first of all how can I prove that. Secondly, what does NTIME mean? Can we use a $k$-Tape Turing machine, when they say NTIME OR NSPACE?
What do both of them mean?

Comment: The exact definition of NTIME depends on the source of this question, although multi-tape Turing machines are the most common model (at least among Turing machines). 
If you are able to use a 2-Tape machine, do you know how to make use of the nondeterminism or is this also part of the question.

Comment: *What does NTIME mean?* That's a question for your professor.

Comment: It seems that crossing sequences can be used to prove that your language requires time $\Omega(n^2)$ on a single-tape nondeterministic Turing machine. This is essentially since the nondeterministic communication complexity of equality of $n$-bit strings is $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: @Aman Shaikh: Do you really mean $\mathsf{NTIME}(n)$ or $\mathsf{NTIME}(\mathcal{O}(n))$? Does your definition of $\mathsf{NTIME}$ already include $\mathcal{O}$ (this also differs between authors)?